# Kotlin inheritance: pass this as constructor argument

Tags: kotlin

Im trying to create a GsonRequest class that extends a normal volley request, and also implements the error listener. The code I'm using to do this is

```
public class GsonRequest<T>(url: String, val clazz: Class<T>) : 
    Request<T>(Request.Method.GET, url, this), ErrorListener
```

However, I'm getting the following error: 'this' is not defined in this context. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: In Java, [you can not](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1_ do this. The reasons is probably that at the point nothing is initialized yet and maybe there's a JVM related reason, too. Anyway, it's risky to do such things.

Answer (score 3):

You can not use `this` on the JVM before the super-constructor finished working, so you can not pass it to the super-constructor.

What you can do is use an object expression or a lambda for an error listener:

```
public class GsonRequest<T>(url: String, val clazz: Class<T>) : 
    Request<T>(Request.Method.GET, url, { <handling code here> } )
```

Alternatively, consider taking the listener as a parameter for constructor of class `GsonRequest`